# Why does Swift think that my array is a function?

Tags: swift

```
// Complete the miniMaxSum function below.
func birthdayCakeCandles(arr: [Int]) -> Int {
    let a = arr.sorted
    let highest = a().last!
    return 0
}

birthdayCakeCandles(arr: [1, 7, 3, 12, 5])
```

I tried to create a sorted array "a" from an unsorted array "arr", to solve a problem from HackerRank.  But compiler gives following error:

> main.swift:5:19: error: function 'a' was used as a property; add () to
>   call it
>
> ```
> let highest = a.last!
>               ^
>                ()
> ```

Why does it think, that "a" is a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> error: function 'a' was used as a property; add () to call it

Swift doesn't think that your array is a function. Xcode just tells you, that `sorted` is a method and you have to call it with `()` at the end

```
let a = arr.sorted()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let a = arr.sorted
```

> Why does it think, that "a" is a function?

Because that is just what it is. `sorted` is the *name* of a function. So `a` is now the `sorted` function.

What you want is for `a` to be the *result of calling* a function. But every function call involves *parentheses*, e.g. `sorted()`. You have no parentheses.

In short that line of your code talks *about* `sorted`. But it never *calls* `sorted`. It just renames it.

Comment: @Carpsen90 `a` has the same address as `sorted`

Comment: Yes but that wasn’t the code with the error that he was asking about.

Answer (score 0):

`arr.sorted` evaluates to a method of `[Int]`. If you want a sorted copy of the array call that method:

```
func birthdayCakeCandles(arr: [Int]) -> Int {
    let a = arr.sorted()
    let highest = a.last!
    return 0
}
```

Otherwise, the compiler is right: `a` contains a function: The `sorted` method.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to do is the following:

```
func birthdayCakeCandles(arr: [Int]) -> Int {
    return arr.max() ?? 0
}
```

---

In your code, `a` is not an array, it is a function with the following signature `() -> [Int]`, because `arr.sorted` is an instance method. You can check the type of a variable by <kbd>Alt</kbd> + clicking on the variable in Xcode. To execute this function you need to invoke it using `()`. Which you are doing in the following line. The output of `a()` is an array of integers, on which you are calling the `last` property.

If your `arr` is empty, `.last!` will cause an error/app crash, since you'd be unwrapping `nil` (there is no last element in an empty array). This is why in the suggested code above, I've used the nil-coalescing operator `??`, which would guarantee that the function would return `0` if the array `arr` is empty.

---

For more in-depth reading on instance methods, have a look [here](https://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/).